# SQL Server Update Case When Then statment

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I need to update a column `[Recipient on contract]` in the table `[Check_Result]`. But the value to insert into the column is not a fixed string but a value from `[All_Contracts]` table. Thus, all rows to inset into `[Recipient on contract]` are unique and can be found with the keys `[ID Contract] = [Référence]`

The link between tables `[Check_Result]` and `[All_Contracts]` is `[ID Contract] = [Référence]`

```
Update [Check_Result]   
set [Recipient on contract] =
 If [Bénéficiaire] ="Personne morale" Then
            If [Organisme]  is not null Then get [Organisme] 
            Else get [Professionnel de santé]
        Else 
            If [Professionnel de santé] is not null Then get [Professionnel de santé]
            Else get [Organisme]
```

Is It possible to use THEN in such situation? with a `Update Case when then (select from inner join where)` statement?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each of the values in [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement can be replaced with nested select statement surrounded with '(' and ')', i.e. this is a valid statement:

```
update table1 set
    field1 = CASE WHEN field2 = 'some value'
                  THEN (select field1 from table2 where table1.key_field = table2.key_field) 
                  ELSE 'some default value'
             END
```

You can do the same with [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement too

```
update table1 set
    field1 = IIF(field2 = 'some value',
                  (select field1 from table2 where table1.key_field = table2.key_field),
                  'some default value')
```

Your update statement isn't quite clear. Which value you want to get from `[All_Contracts]` table? It can simplified like this:

```
Update [Check_Result] set
    [Recipient on contract] = IIF([Bénéficiaire] = "Personne morale",
        COALESCE([Organisme], [Professionnel de santé]), 
        COALESCE([Professionnel de santé], [Organisme]))
```

There you can replace `[Professionnel de santé]` or `[Organisme]` with `(select SomeField from [All_Contracts] where [All_Contracts].[ID Contract] = [Check_Result].[Référence])`.